# Detect the line ending character of a csv file

Tags: php, csv, line-endings

I need to detect what kind of line endings are in a csv file:

- `\n` (UNIX default)
- `\r` (Mac Excel)
- `\r\n` (Windows)
- or anything else

To get the delimeter, encosure & escape character, I used [SplFileObject::getCsvControl](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.getcsvcontrol.php) - would be to great to have something like that for the line ending char.

Opening the file

Comment: in general case - you cannot detect it, for example file could have mixed line endings, what is your real problem?

Comment: Not sure what all functions use it but: `ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);` As for `SplFileObject::getCsvControl`, _Note that this function does not magically guess the CSV control from a given file, rather it returns what has been priorly set with SplFileObject::setCsvControl()._

Comment: @IlyaBursov I need to import a csv to my MySQL db with LOAD DATA INFILE, but that query has to have the line ending character explicitly defined.

Comment: @AbraCadaver i didn't know that! Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: LOAD DATA INFILE does not require ending character, anyway - if you want to upload any csv file provided by users with unknown delimiters, endings - the only robust way is to ask these details from uploader, you cannot correctly guess it from file itself

Comment: I'd normalize files with `\r\n` down to `\n` and then you should not need to specify `LINES TERMINATED BY` at all for LOAD DATA INFILE. Assume large files and wanting to avoid iteration in PHP - perhaps use d2u/dos2unix. Otherwise some perl/sed/tr etc should work.

Comment: btw since many do not know about it: mysql has a builtin csv-storage-engine. so in some use-cases you could skip LOAD DATA INFILE and just copy the file to some locations (yes links out of the db directory work) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/csv-storage-engine.html

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this, but I thought it was an interesting problem so here's my crack at a possible solution:

```
// first, have PHP auto-detect the line endings, like @AbraCadaver suggested:
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);

// now open the file and read a single line from it
$file = fopen('/path/to/file.csv', 'r');
fgets($file);

// fgets() moves the pointer, so get the current position
$position = ftell($file);

// now get a couple bytes (here: 10) from around that position
fseek($file, $position - 5);
$data = fread($file, 10);

// we no longer need the file
fclose($file);

// now find out how many of each type EOL there are in those 10 bytes
// expected result is that two of these will be 0 and one will be 1
$eols = array(
    "\r\n" => substr_count($data, "\r\n"),
    "\r" => substr_count($data, "\r"),
    "\n" => substr_count($data, "\n"),
);

// sort the EOL count in reverse order, so that the EOL with the highest
// count (expected: 1) will be the first item
arsort($eols);

// get the first item's key
$eol = key($eols);

// $eol will now be "\r\n", "\r" or "\n"
```

There are probably better ways of doing this, and note that I'm making some assumptions about your CSV file here:

- the file does not start with an empty line;
- the first line is at least 5 bytes long;
- the second line is not empty and is also at least 5 bytes long;
- the last column of the first line and the first column of the last line do not contain any line breaks within them;
- you're not dealing with a file that has mixed line endings.

If you cannot count on these conditions, you'll have to add some validation steps, like checking if the result of `fgets()` was actually a string of several characters. If lines can be shorter than 5 bytes, you may also have to account for the fact that the line ending *could* be `\r\n`, but by seeking into raw bytes we happen to end up with a string like `"abcde\r\nfg\r"`, where we just missed out on the second `\n` and you'll get an incorrect result.

But if you can be sure about the CSV file's construction, this might be a (dirty, I'll admit) step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It is an interesting problem - and nobody will be able to give you a complete solution here. The obvious approaches are:

1) keep reading the file until the first occurrence of \r or \n. In the case of the former, read one more character to check if it is followed by \n.

This sounds really simple - but you need to implement quote handling to determine if the EOL is embedded in a quoted data field - and you don't know how the data is quoted. In addition to detecting the opening and closing quotes, you also need to be able to determine if the quote character is escaped - and there are at least 2 different ways of escaping quote characters.

2) Analyse the frequency of the characters in the file. If you can ignore spaces, alhpa chars and numbers, then the most frequent of the remainder should be the CSV meta characters. But those won't work for very short files.

3) create a representation of the data strings in the file and look for recorruing patterns e.g. if you found number, space, alpha, space, number, punctuation, number, spache, alpha, punctuation, alpha, space, number, punctuation, number, space, alpha, space, number, punctuation then you might presume that the field seperator was a space, and the records were delimited by the punctuation, which could also appear as an embedded character.

But this requires some very complex code.

If it were me, I would just ask whoever supplied the file to supply the details of the file format. Or if that information were not available, then open the file with a hex editor.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the @rickdenhaan solution and I've found a problem with arsort() and PHP Version.

if eol is "\r\n" the $eols array will be:

array("\r\n" => 1, "\r" => 1, "\n" => 1);

(because in addition to 1 "\r\n" is also found 1 "\r" and 1 "\n")

and with **PHP 7**, after arsort($eols), the keys order is the same:

array("\r\n" => 1, "\r" => 1, "\n" => 1);

and after the "$eol = key($eols);" $eol will be "\r\n"

But with **PHP 5.6**, after arsort($eols), the keys order is:

array("\n" => 1, "\r" => 1, "\r\n" => 1);

and after the "$eol = key($eols);" $eol will be "\n"

I've solved with this check after "$eol = key($eols);":

```
if (($eols["\r\n"] == $eols["\r"]) AND ($eols["\r\n"] == $eols["\n"])) {
    $line_separator = "\r\n";
}
```